# Vim - surround comment line with comment character

Tags: code-golf, vim, comment

Today I realised that I often like to define sections in my code like so:

```
####################
# Helper Functions #
####################
```

But that it's tedious to do. Assuming I have a line such as this:

```
# Helper Functions #
```

What is the shortest set of `vim` keystrokes to wrap it in a `#`? Shift does **not** count as a keystroke in this challenge.

Test cases:

```
Input: "#test test test#"
Output:
################
#test test test#
################

Input: "#this is a nice block comment#"
Output:
##############################
#this is a nice block comment#
##############################

Input: "# s p a c e s must be supported a l s o#"
Output:
########################################
# s p a c e s must be supported a l s o#
########################################
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "vim keystrokes" basically means running commands of an IDE, like Ctrl - C, or Ctrl - R in ST2. This is not coding in any form.

Comment: @Optimizer Vim is a turing complete language (e.g. by using macros) with several different constructs coding and the primary method for editing is based on verbs (actions) an objects (movements). There is already a popular web page for vim golfing: www.vimgolf.com. (But I agree that this particular question is pretty boring)

Comment: @Optimizer: is there a more suitable S.E. site the question could be moved to? Given vim's extensive scripting/macro language, some people might consider it a language in itself.

Comment: Supposedly most other PPCG big shots also think the same as you do. But both the above comments/arguments hold true for any good IDE, like ST2 or IntelliJ or Atom

Comment: @Optimizer I have no idea what PPCG means, but your response sounds surprisingly hostile for what I thought was a reasonable reply to your comment.

Comment: @Optimizer So there is a www.IntelliJgolf.com as well? :P

Comment: @shearn89 Hostile ? What are you talking about ? PPCG is this site.

Comment: @Hjulle so treat a random webpage as a proof :D

Comment: @Optimizer - ahhh that makes more sense! I interpreted it as you calling myself a "PPCG bigshot", and assumed the PPCG was derogatory. My bad!

Comment: Why wouldn't other IDE's be allowed as well if you can write programs in their macro system? What is it that makes it "not programming"?

Comment: I like this question, because I also do this =D

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### <s>11</s> <s>8</s> 7 keystrokes

```
YpVkr#p

Yp - duplicate current line, leaving the cursor at the lower of the two
V - enter visual line mode
k - go up and select both lines
r# - replace every selected character with #. Leaves visual mode and leaves cursor at the upper line.
p - put the yanked line (the original) on the next line.
```

(thanks to doorknob for reminding Y=yy)

Comment: Replace `yy` with `Y` to save a character.

Comment: Wow, that `r` command is powerful

Answer (score 10):

## <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 14 keystrokes

```
Yp
:s/./#/g
<cr>
YkP
```

The straight-forward approach: duplicate the line, replace all characters with `#`, copy the the result and paste it above.

I'm counting `P` and `:` as one keystroke each (instead of two for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>). That being said, the question specifies to count "commands", where I'm not sure how to count the substitution.

Comment: Same comment as on @rcrmn's answer: Replace `yy` with `Y` to save a character.

Comment: I believe it's actually 14 keystrokes, as you have to hit Intro to execute the replace command

Comment: @rcrmn Oh, good catch.